# Good implementation of sending data to a REST api?

Tags: mysql, api, rest

Each day hundreds of thousands of items are inserted, updated and deleted on our service (backend using .Net and a MySql database).

Now we are integrating our service with another service using their RESTful API. Each time an item is inserted, updated or deleted on our service we also need to connect to their web service and use POST, PUT, DELETE.

What is a good implementation of this case?

It seems like not a very good idea to connect to their API each time a user inserts an item on our service as it would be a quite slow experience for the user.

Another idea was to update our database like usual. Then set up another server constant connecting to our database and fetching data that needs to be posted to the RESTful API. Is this the way to go?

How would you solve it? Any guides of implementing stuff like this would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you delay in updating the other service is acceptable or not. If not, than create a event and put this in queue of event processor who can send this to second service.
If delay is acceptable than there can be background batch job that can run periodically and send the data.

Comment: A small delay is fine. My idea is to build an app running in Windows fetching data and posting to the API. Thanks!